# Istio - access external DB (TCP) with DNS name

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I want to access external DB which is exposed on some ip: 10.48.100.124 (there is no DNS name associated with this IP) with port 3306
I have create ServiceEntry:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: csd-database
  namespace: testnam-dev
spec:
  hosts:
    - csd-database
  addresses:
    - 10.48.100.124/32
  exportTo:
    - "."
  ports:
    - number: 3306
      name: tcp
      protocol: TCP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: STATIC
  endpoints:
    - address: 10.48.100.124
      ports:
        tcp: 3306
```

And it works ok if I try to connect via IP (10.48.100.124) inside cluster.
But I want to expose this service (inside k8s/isito cluster) with DNS name so I have create VirtualService:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: csd-database
  namespace: testnam-dev
spec:
  hosts:
    - csd-database
  gateways:
    - ingresgateway
  tcp:
  - route:
    - destination:
       host: csd-database
```

But I'm not able to connect to host: csd-database
Also telnet is unable to connect to csd-database on 3306 port.
How I can expose ServiceEntry with DNS name inside cluster ?

DB dosn't have DNS name (externaly) it has only IP address. SO DB is accesible only on 10.48.100.124:3306

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Your `ServiceEntry` currently is configured to resolve by static ip address.

Change:

```
resolution: STATIC
```

to

```
resolution: DNS
```

---

According to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/#ServiceEntry-Resolution):

> ### ServiceEntry.Resolution
>
> Resolution determines how the proxy will resolve the IP addresses of
> the network endpoints associated with the service, so that it can
> route to one of them. The resolution mode specified here has no impact
> on how the application resolves the IP address associated with the
> service. The application may still have to use DNS to resolve the
> service to an IP so that the outbound traffic can be captured by the
> Proxy. Alternatively, for HTTP services, the application could
> directly communicate with the proxy (e.g., by setting HTTP_PROXY) to
> talk to these services.
>
> `NONE` - Assume that incoming connections have already been resolved
> (to a specific destination IP address). Such connections are typically
> routed via the proxy using mechanisms such as IP table REDIRECT/ eBPF.
> After performing any routing related transformations, the proxy will
> forward the connection to the IP address to which the connection was
> bound.
>
> `STATIC` - Use the static IP addresses specified in endpoints (see
> below) as the backing instances associated with the service.
>
> `DNS` - Attempt to resolve the IP address by querying the ambient DNS,
> during request processing. If no endpoints are specified, the proxy
> will resolve the DNS address specified in the hosts field, if
> wildcards are not used. If endpoints are specified, the DNS addresses
> specified in the endpoints will be resolved to determine the
> destination IP address. DNS resolution cannot be used with Unix domain
> socket endpoints.

Comment: actualy it dosn't work. I need to add to my question: this DB dosn't have dns name assigned to ip - it has only IP address